# Does Selenium 4 support for jpms now

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I recently aware of jpms and tried implementing selenium as java modular project using java 10.

I was looking into the selenium 4 documentation and found that the initial support of jpms was tried in 3.14 base version and better implementation of java 9  plus version modules in Selenium 4 alpha version 2 and 3.

I created a maven project and added selenium 4 alpha version 3 as dependency and created a project with module file.

As per maven, what ever the dependent file type it will work fine and add the dependent files in m2 folder.

Maven created a new folder seleniumHQ with dependent files(I believe it should be module file).

In my module-info.java I add required selenium.java and in main class when I try to import Org.openqa.selenium package it does not exist.

Please guide me I am new here. If any one have tutorial link for jpms selenium plz post

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: No, the last thing I saw was, a issue was already raised for this. Not sure if its working now or not